# SafeAreaView ref generates a Typescript error

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript, safeareaview

I'm getting a stragne error in TypeScript **SafeAreaView** component. I crated other refs for WebView and it doesn't fail, only seems to fail when assigned to the SafeAreaView component.

```
import { useRef, MutableRefObject } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
...
...
const topSafeAreaViewRef = useRef(null);
...
...
<SafeAreaView ref={topSafeAreaViewRef} style={styles.container} edges={['top', 'right', 'left']} >
```

> TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; ref: MutableRefObject; style:
> { flex: number; backgroundColor: any; }; edges: ("top" | "right" |
> "left")[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> ViewProps & { children?: ReactNode; mode?: "padding" | "margin" |
> undefined; edges?: readonly Edge[] | undefined; }'.   Property 'ref'
> does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ViewProps & { children?:
> ReactNode; mode?: "padding" | "margin" | undefined; edges?: readonly
> Edge[] | undefined; }'.

I need ref because I need to set **setNativeProps** on an external function

```
const handleOnLoadEnd = (
    syntheticEvent: WebViewNavigationEvent | WebViewErrorEvent,
    topSafeAreaViewRef: MutableRefObject<any>,
) => {
  topSafeAreaViewRef.current.setNativeProps({
    style:{
      backgroundColor: Constants?.manifest?.extra?.webViewBackground,
    }
  });

};
```

Answer (score 2):

The `react-native-safe-area-context`'s `SafeAreaView` component doesn't support `ref` prop.

If you need the `ref` to calculate width, height, etc., you can try a workaround like this (Untested):

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  return (
    <View
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        paddingTop: insets.top,
        paddingLeft: insets.left,
        paddingBottom: insets.bottom,
        paddingRight: insets.right,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention my use case, just check my updated question and thanks for the hints!

Comment: @razor7 Ok I think still you can use this workaround. Tell me if not

Answer (score 0):

**SafeAreaView** is the preferred way to consume insets. This is a regular `View` with insets applied as extra padding or margin. It offers better performance by applying insets natively and avoids flickers that can happen with the other JS based consumers.

**SafeAreaView** is a regular View component with the safe area insets applied as padding or margin.

Padding or margin styles are added to the insets, for example `style={{paddingTop: 10}}` on a **SafeAreaView** that has insets of 20 will result in a top padding of 30.

**Example:**

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

**Edges:**

Optional, array of top, right, bottom, and left. Defaults to all.

Sets the edges to apply the safe area insets to.

For example if you don't want insets to apply to the top edge because the view does not touch the top of the screen you can use:

```
<SafeAreaView edges={['right', 'bottom', 'left']} />
```

For further Details or Documentation you can check [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context)

You should remove `useRef()` because useRef is not Sported in SafeAreaView.

Comment: What are you trying to explain? I think this information is not related to the question

Comment: All of above details explains that SafeAreaView have all of that properties which View tag have.But It doesn't support ref props.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention my use case, just check my updated question and thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

In my experimentation it seems like the `ref` actually *does* work.  The `SafeAreaView` passes all of its props down to the underlying `View` component.  But it [doesn't use `forwardRef`](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/blob/dfa9aebd1c1149395f476d16b81625427d5ee99c/src/SafeAreaView.tsx#L22), so it seems like it *shouldn't* work.

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/_KvLST3LN) -- the background will turn red when the `WebView` has loaded (on iOS).

If it does what you want and it's just a TypeScript error, you can always use `// @ts-ignore`.  It's not an ideal solution but it's probably the easiest.

---

> I need ref because I need to set `setNativeProps` on an external function

I would recommend trying to structure your components such that you can control the style via props and don't need to use refs or `setNativeProps`.  I'm not sure of the relationship between your `WebView` and your `SafeAreaView`, but try something like this:

```
interface ComponentWithWebViewProps {
  setStyle: (style: ViewStyle) => void;
}

const ComponentWithWebView = ({ setStyle }: ComponentWithWebViewProps) => {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{
        uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848728/safeareaview-ref-generates-a-typescript-error/',
      }}
      onLoadEnd={() =>
        setStyle({
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        })
      }
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    />
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  // These are the extra/override styles that we are adding.
  const [customStyle, setCustomStyle] = React.useState<ViewStyle>({});
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      // Can pass multiple styles in an array
      style={[styles.container, customStyle]}
      edges={['top', 'right', 'left']}>
      <Text>Hello, World</Text>
      <ComponentWithWebView setStyle={setCustomStyle} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <ParentComponent />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@lindapaiste/1ed295)